# How to add New Div in Particullar Magento Block

Tags: magento

I want to insert new div in product-options-bottom div. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4):

Find the `phtml` file in the base theme that contains your div

```
#File: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml
<div class="product-options-bottom">
...
</div>
```

Then, copy the `catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml` in your theme

```
app/design/frontend/[package_name]/[theme_name]/template/catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml
```

and edit it to your heart's content.